# IntelliJ 14 aggressive trailing whitespace removing

Tags: intellij-idea, whitespace, intellij-14, removing-whitespace

I've been using IntelliJ for years and switched to IntelliJ 14 yesterday. Something I don't like is the overly aggressive trailing whitespace remover. Basically I'm typing in a pom.xml file and if I stop for one second to think about the next word I'm going to type the IntelliJ editor removes the space and I have to retype it.

I checked the editor properties but was unable to find this new "feature" so I can't disable it. (I already clear trailing whitespaces on save, so I'm not sure why this is needed while I'm typing)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638361/intellij-13-is-removing-trailing-white-space-as-it-is-being-typed

Comment: You might want to look at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-120553, there are some "trouble shooting" steps in the comments and a possible work around. You might also want to open a issue with IntelliJ.

Comment: That's interesting. I just checked and yes it looks like my pom.xml file is autosaving a second or so after I stop typing.

Comment: Have you tried turning off the automatic make? "Settings|Compiler|make project automatically"

Comment: It's not the make, I had removing trailing spaces on save turned on and since pom.xml files automatically save every second it was deleting it. I have no idea why I never saw this on 13, possibly it was a configuration difference when I migrated.

Comment: This happens in literally all my files at the moment. Drives me nuts.